# JQuery find closest parent tr in nested tr

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, parent, closest

How can I find the parent tr from the closest child tr e.g. from the second child tr, how can I get to the first parent tr?

Below are two table structures I have been using:

1)

```
 <table>
        <tr class="menu">
            <td><input type='text' class='parent' value='First Parent'></td>  
            <tr class="sub-menu">
                <td><input type='text' class='firstchild' value='First Child'>
                </td>

            </tr>
             <tr class="sub-menu">
                <td><input type='text' class='secondchild' value='Second Child'>
                </td>
            </tr>   
        </tr>
            <tr class="menu" >
            <td ><input type='text' class='parent' value='Second Parent'></td> 
            <tr class="sub-menu">
                <td><input type='text' class='firstchild' value='First Child'>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

2)

```
    <table>
    <tr class="menu">
        <td><input type='text' class='parent' value='First Parent'></td>  
</tr>
        <tr class="sub-menu">
            <td><input type='text' class='child' value='First Child'>
            </td>
      </tr>

         <tr class="sub-menu">
            <td><input type='text' class='child' value='Second Child'>
            </td>
        </tr>   
    <tr  class="menu">

        <td><input type='text' class='parent' value='Second Parent'></td>  </tr>
        <tr class="sub-menu">
            <td><input type='text' class='child' value='First Child'>
            </td>
            </tr>

</table>
```

I have tried the following JQuery code:

```
$(this).closest('tr.submenu').closest('tr.menu').find('.parent').val();

$(this).closest('tr.submenu').parent('tr.menu').find('.parent').val();

$(this).closest('tr.menu').find('.parent').val();

$(this).closest('tr.submenu').prevUntil('tr.menu').find('.parent').val();

$(this).closest('tr.submenu').parentsUntil('tr.menu').find('.parent').val();

$(this).closest('tr.submenu').parents(':first-child').find('.parent').val();
```

All attempts have failed. How can I get the parent value from the closest sub menu tr?

Comment: This code is invalid. You cannot nest a `tr` in another `tr`.

Comment: [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is not what you want. It only applies to form element values. Use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: .parent is a form element

Comment: like @KevinBoucher said its not valid html and the class names are of in your html its `sub-menu` in your jquery is `submenu`, when that should be `.sub-menu`. but you should look at some basic html and css and the concept of classes before trying jquery.

Comment: this is just a sample of my coding, I forgot to change the html coding here.

Comment: I have also added another table structure without nested tr. I would like to know the jquery to find the parent tr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found the solution:

```
$('.child').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.parents('tr').prevAll("tr.menu:first").css("background-color", "yellow");

});
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, your table structures are incorrect.

You cannot nest `<tr>` tags, without defining a sub-table.

I've fixed your table structure, and provided some jQuery that does what I think you're trying to do.  Why you're using tables and inputs for a menu is beyond me.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
     <tr class="menu">
         <td><input type='text' class='parent' value='First Parent' /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="sub-menu">
         <td><input type='text' class='firstchild' value='First Child' /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="sub-menu">
         <td><input type='text' class='secondchild' value='Second Child' /></td>  
     </tr>
     <tr class="menu" >
         <td ><input type='text' class='parent' value='Second Parent' /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="sub-menu">
         <td><input type='text' class='firstchild' value='First Child' /></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS** (for visual effect):

```
table td { padding: 10px; }
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.firstchild').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.parents('tr').prev().css("background-color", "yellow");

});
```

You can view the results here: http://jsfiddle.net/357tE/

Click on the "First Child" inputs, and it will highlight the "First Parent" that comes before that child.

Comment: Thank you, I have already tried that but does not work.

Comment: It would help if you told us what `$(this)` is. Without that context, we don't know exactly where the starting point is.

Comment: @someone I've updated my answer with code and a working example.

Comment: Again, just an example of my coding- not actually a menu :) I haven't applied what $(this) is within the coding, but $(this) would be if a button is clicked from the submenu next to the input textbox.

Comment: I purposely called all the submenu class names child. I wanted to know how you can go to the parent element from any child element.

Comment: Nevermind, found the solution. Thanks for you help.